# How to use exception architecture

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use xception model to classify images,but iam getting valuerror.

```
xception=keras.applications.xception.Xception(include_top=False,input_shape=(71,71,3))
classifier=Sequential()
for layer in xception.layers:
    classifier.add(layer)
```

Iam getting this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 64 but got shape (None, 33, 33, 128)
```

I also get this error when using resnet.But i dont get it when iam using vgg16 or vgg19.Can anyone say how to use it??

Comment: I do not why we are getting this, but you can use the functional api to avoid this error

Comment: Can you please say what it means to use functional api?

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: `input_tensor=Input(shape=(71,71,3))
xception=keras.applications.xception.Xception(include_top=False,input_tensor=input_tensor)`.This worked

Comment: Haha I just wrote the same thing

Comment: Yes.I looked into keras,tried it and came back to stack overflow to this.THanks for the help.I had head ache bcoz of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functional API. Here is one possible example of classifier

```
#Base model Xception
xception=keras.applications.xception.Xception(include_top=False,input_shape=(71,71,3))

# Input of your model
input=Input(shape=(71,71,3))
# Add the inception base model to your model
y=xception(input)
    .

    .
# Other layers by passing previous output  
y=Dense(...)(y)
# Define model
model=Model(input,y)
```

[Docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Comment: Dont we have to flatten it.How to do in this?

Comment: Thats one way to do it

Comment: GlobalaveragePooling2D and flattening are same or different?

Comment: They are different